# I can't get numbering on my roman 3 pages

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, numbering, emptypage

So I am trying to number the pages (Abstract, Acknowledgments, Abbreviations) with roman and not showing the header. I can get the numbering in the table of content but not on the page itself.

Moreover, the roman numbering in the table of content looks like (i,ii,iii) but there are empty pages in between. Why it doesn't take them into consideration.

PS: The other numbering (Arabic) starting from introduction is working correctly.

```
    \newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\section*{STATUTORYD ECLARATION}
\end{center}
thesis has not been submitted to any other board of examiners yet.
\\
\\
\\
\\
January 5, 2020
    \shipout\null
    \newpage
    \shipout\null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \begin{center}
\section*{Abstract}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
    \newpage
    \shipout\null
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
\section*{Acknowledgments}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
    \newpage
    \shipout\null
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
\section*{Abbreviations}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \listoftables
    \newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}    
\section{Introduction} % (fold)
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you ***sure*** about littering your document with `\shipout\null` commands? Do you ***know*** what `\shipout\null` does?

Comment: Thank you! I am using it to create empty pages. That's what I read online.

Comment: Well, no. That's definitely not the best way to create an empty page; try `\cleardoublepage` instead. What document class are you using?

Comment: I replaced \shipout\null with \cleardoublepage however, the empty pages gone. I am using \documentclass[a4paper]{article}.

Comment: If you want two-side printing, you should add the `twoside` option to the document class. Otherwise, what would be the purpose of those blank pages?

Comment: That fixed the empty pages. Now the problem still the numbering is not there. Now in the TOC I can see (i,iii,v)